# Why are there different ways to import Modules in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, commonjs

I am unsure the differences between importing a JavaScript module in the following:

- CommonJS
- ES5
- ES6
- NodeJS
- Typescript

Why are there so many ways to import javascript modules? Is "module" defined differently in different implementations? Are all doing the same thing but with different syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no modules in ES5 and earlier. Various module systems (CommonJS, AMD, and the CommonJS-like ones in and Node.js and TypeScript) were created because there was no standard module system in JavaScript at the time, but it's a really useful thing to have. So the need got filled by tools and toolbuilders.

ES2015 (aka "ES6") created a standard syntax for modules in JavaScript which has now been adopted by all modern browsers, Node.js, and TypeScript. That standard syntax leaves the semantics of module identifiers up to the host environment, so leaders in the web community had to come to consensus for how to do them in browsers (and Node.js had to figure out how to do it in Node.js, etc.), so there was a bit of a delay between ES2015 coming out and your being able to use that syntax natively (though Webpack, Rollup, and such handled it).

There are some use cases where ES2015's static syntax doesn't quite do the job, so there's the [`import()` (dynamic import) proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) which is already supported in some environments and will be in ES2020.

Comment: `<opinion>`
Now that there is a standard syntax and broad support for it, including `import()` for dynamic cases, I suspect that usage of CommonJS and such will diminish over time. But that said, the tools that support CommonJS and such will probably continue to do so for quite some time, so they may well continue to be used. But -- again, this is opinion -- the standard syntax is probably the future if not largely the present.
`</opinion>`

Comment: Thanks!!! To sum up if my intent were to learn best practices for latest web dev (Nov 2019), I would use ES6 module imports for vanilla JS, and use the node module system in Node.js? If you want you can help clarify my vocabulary... "node module system" sounds odd

Comment: @MM. - You can use ESM (as the JavaScript module system has come to be known, **E**CMA**S**cript **M**odules) in Node.js now as well. :-) In v13.something it's shipping unflagged. In v12 it was behind a flag. So just one set of semantics to learn, unless you end up working on a project that uses CommonJS or AMD for legacy reasons (or just for preference reasons).